# gRPC Context return null when I use SimpleForwardingServerCallListener

Tags: java, kotlin, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-kotlin

I want to override `sendMessage`, `sendHeaders`, `onMessage`, `onHalfClose` methods in `ServerInterceptor` (with `Context`):

```
val context = Context.current().withValue(TestConstants.CONTEXT_KEY, "testValue1")
val delegatedCall = object : SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {

    override fun sendMessage(message: RespT) {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.sendMessage(message)
        super.sendMessage(message)
    }

    override fun sendHeaders(headers: Metadata) {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.sendHeaders(headers)
        super.sendHeaders(headers)
    }

    override fun close(status: Status, trailers: Metadata) {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.close(status, trailers)
        super.close(status, trailers)
    }
}
val delegatedListener: ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> =
    if (context === null)
        next.startCall(delegatedCall, headers)
    else
        Contexts.interceptCall(context, delegatedCall, headers, next)

return object : ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(delegatedListener) {

    override fun onMessage(message: ReqT) {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.onMessage(message, headers)
        super.onMessage(message)
    }

    override fun onHalfClose() {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.onHalfClose(headers)
        super.onHalfClose()
    }

    override fun onCancel() {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.onCancel(headers)
        super.onCancel()
    }

    override fun onComplete() {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.onComplete(headers)
        super.onComplete()
    }

    override fun onReady() {
        this@SimpleServerInterceptor.onReady(headers)
        super.onReady()
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
>>>>intercept1
>>>>intercept2: testValue1
>>>>onReady1: null
>>>>onMessage1: null
>>>>onHalfClose1: null
HelloService3.hello: testValue1
>>>>sendHeaders2: testValue1
>>>>sendHeaders1: testValue1
>>>>sendMessage2: testValue1
>>>>sendMessage1: testValue1
```

You can see that `Context` is valid for `delegatedCall`(`sendMessage`, `sendHeaders`) but invalid for `delegatedListener`(`onMessage`, `onHalfClose`).

Why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: How are `ReqT` and `RespT` defined?

Comment: @MichielLeegwater just use gRPC default, no defined

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that *that specific* `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` isn't seeing the change because it is executed *before* the listener within `Contexts.interceptCall()`. The Listener is used for callbacks, so they are called by gRPC. gRPC will call the listener returned, and that listener will end up calling `delegatedListener` and `delegatedListener` is the one that does the Context adjusting. `Contexts.interceptCall()` doesn't change `call` at all, so the fact that the calls see the Context means that the Listener *must* be working correctly.

I suggest making a `ServerCallHandler` that does all the calls to `SimpleServerInterceptor` and passing that handler to `Contexts.interceptCall()`.

(Just a sketch, since I am not familiar with Kotlin)

```kotlin
val context = Context.current().withValue(TestConstants.CONTEXT_KEY, "testValue1")
if (context === null) // Unclear how this will be null
    return next.startCall(delegatedCall, headers)
else
    return Contexts.interceptCall(context, delegatedCall, headers, new SimpleServerInterceptorHandler(next))

...

// Within SimpleServerInterceptorHandler
val delegatedCall = object : SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
  ...
}
val delegatedListener: ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> =
        next.startCall(delegatedCall, headers)
return object : ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(delegatedListener) {
  ...
}
```